# Hoisting / Returning variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, return, hoisting

I have the following code to query a MongoDB database:

```
   var docs;

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  findDocuments(db, function() {
    console.log(docs);
    client.close();
  });
});

const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
    // Get the documents collection
    const collection = db.collection('oee');
    // Find some documents
    collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      console.log("Found the following records");
      //console.log(docs);
      callback(docs);
      return docs;   
    });
  };
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Connected successfully to server
Found the following records
undefined
```

I want to use the results of the query which are stored inthe variable docs for further processing. However they don´t get returned from the function. i.e. the the expression

```
   findDocuments(db, function() {
    console.log(docs);
    client.close();
  });
```

I get an "undefined" returned. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the findDocuments function call as follows,

```
findDocuments(db, function(docs) {
     console.log(docs);
     client.close();
});
```

You don't need the `docs` variable at the top. Use local variables as follows,

```
const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
     // Get the documents collection
     const collection = db.collection('oee');
     // Find some documents
     collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, docs) {
         assert.equal(err, null);
         console.log("Found the following records");
         return callback(docs);   
     });
 }
```

Also note that I removed the `return docs` statement, as it doesn't have any importance along with the callback.

Finally, I suggest you to learn more about callbacks (and preferably promises)

Comment: thanks, very helpfull to get a better understanding of callabacks. I got confused because of the nested functions. What would be needed to make 'docs' available outside the MongoClient.connect function scope?

Comment: You can use a global variable(say `var docs_global`) for that matter. Then you can assign the value of `docs` to `docs_global`. But I wouldn't recommend that practice. If you need to maintain a global state, I suggest on using the new ES6 class syntax

Answer (score 0):

Change this
 `function() {
    console.log(docs);
    client.close();
  });`
to this

```
function(docs) {
console.log(docs);
client.close();
```

});
because in your code you log **docs** variable on the top of your code which hadn't receive any value try the new code and tell me . does it work now ? I think yes .

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both answers are correct and working?

Comment: You're are welcome can you vote it ?